# Handsontable Nested Headers - Collapsed by Default

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Does anyone know how to make the nested headers plugin for Handsontable collapse a specific set of columns by default (i.e. when the table initially loads up)?

Specifically I have the following appearing:

[image: Nested Headers Current]

And I would like the following to appear:

[image: Nested Headers Desired]

Here is my current code:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(8, 8)
  , rowHeaders: true
  , colHeaders: true
  , columnSorting: true
  , hiddenColumns: true
  , afterRender: function () {
    console.log("render");
  }
  , nestedHeaders: [
            ['Key', {label: 'Design Data', colspan: 7}]
            , ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
          ]
        , collapsibleColumns: [
          {row: -2, col: 1, collapsible: true}
        ]
    });
```

I have created a fiddle showing this below.

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/4bcgdfxL/